# how to go back to previous page if one page can be accessed in different route in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, routes

I have a problem with routing
as you may see in the image there one page that can be accessed in many different routes but the problem that I have is when I try to go back to the previous page it always navigates to root which is home
and I am trying to make this app for both ios and android and in android phone, there is a physical back button if I were to be able to solve it with some weird code I may still have a problem with android due to the physical back button

```
back(){
    let navigation = localStorage.getItem("navigation");
    var routes = navigation.split(",");
    var back_page =routes[routes.length-2];
    
    if(routes.length<2){
     localStorage.setItem("navigation", routes.toString());
    this.router.navigate(['/sidemenu/home'], { replaceUrl: true });
    }
    else{
    localStorage.setItem("navigation", routes.toString());
     this.router.navigate([back_page], { replaceUrl: true });
  
    }
}
```

[image: image route]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with NavController's back()

```
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
 ....
 constructor(
        private navController: NavController
      ) {}
    ...
    back() { 
       this.navController.back();
    }
```

..